# Rotational invariance of Casimir Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

In quantum mechanics, I read that, square of the angular momentum operator (or Casimir operator) $\hat{L}^2$ commutes with angular momentum in $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions.

Now my question is, since $\hat{L}^2$ commutes with $\hat{L}_x$, $\hat{L}_y$ and $\hat{L}_z$, then it must be rotationally invariant. But when we write $\hat{L}^2$ in operator form in spherical coordinates, we see its dependence on angular terms $$-\frac{L^2}{\hbar^2} = \left(\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\partial_{\theta}\sin\theta\ \partial_{\theta} +\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\partial_{\phi}^2\right).$$
How is this possible?

Comment: You can think of it as the magnitude of a vector, then it doesn't change after you rotate the vector.

Comment: Then why it depends on $\theta$ and $\phi$ @ÁlvaroLuque

Comment: You understand its only null eigenfunction is $Y_{00}$, right?

Comment: I lack in physical interpretation of harmonics, but I think the answer is $L^2 $ does not commute with all Lx,Ly,Lz simultaneously, but it commutes with one at a time? @Cosmas Zachos

Comment: It doesn't depend on $\phi$, just on $\theta$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos it wasn't meant to be a deep comment, just that the prefactors only depend on $\theta$ and not on $\phi$. Of course derivatives wrt both of them are present. The $\theta$ dependence is not surprising given the way the co-ordinate chart treats the North pole as special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L^2$ commutes with all three  operators $\vec L$, simultaneously, all right:
$$[L^2,\vec L ]=0.$$ It is a scalar. This means that if you rotated away the north pole and the Greenwich origin of meridians, the transformed operator would look the same in terms of the new longitude φ  and latitude π/2-θ.

So, you are asking, I imagine, what does it *need* these angles for? It is an operator (Casimir invariant) that reads *how* rotational variants rotate into something different. The typical basis for such are [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) $Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$,
the eigenfunctions of $L^2$ and $L_z$, simultaneously diagonalizable since they commute. (It is $L_x$ and $L_y$ which do not commute with $L_z$ and are left out of the game.)
$$
L^2  Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)=   l(l+1)~Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)  , \qquad     L_z~Y_l^m(\theta, \phi) =m Y_l^m(\theta, \phi),
$$
for integer *l* and $-l\leq m \leq l$, as you are probably learning. So This invariant Casimir must depend on the two spherical angles, if it is to monitor the objects that vary with rotations.

It basically breaks variant functions into  representations, collections of functions rotating into each other, but *not* other such functions with a different "label" *l*. This is the point of invariance: no rotation will change your *l* if you're such a function. By use of linear algebra, and [Wigner rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix), you may monitor and quantify such rotations in an elegant, systematic way your are presumably learning about. This is how Wigner  as much as changed our mental world  around 1930.

Comment: Great answer. This question was bugging my mind a bit too

Comment: Thankyou sir, now I got this.